# conditional expectation under convex combinaison of probability measures(II)

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ denote some measurable space. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ denote respectively two probability measures. Now let $\mathcal{G}$ be some sub sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Given a positive integrable random variable $X$, we can define respectively the conditional expectation

$$Y_1=E^{P_1}[X|\mathcal{G}],~ Y_2=E^{P_2}[X|\mathcal{G}]$$

Now for some $0<\alpha<1$, we can define a new probability measure $P=\alpha P_1+(1-\alpha)P_2$, then we get

$$Y=E^{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]$$

Now my question is whether we can prove

$$\operatorname{esssup}{}_P(Y)\le \max\Big( \operatorname{esssup}_{P_1}(Y_1), \operatorname{esssup}_{P_2}(Y_2)\Big)?$$

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Doesn't this follow since $Y$ is a convex combination of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?

Comment: It is not so evident since the $esssup$ are taken under different probability measures...

Comment: I think you can say there's only one measure, namely $P$, and say that everything ($P_1$ and $P_2$) are abs. cts. with respect to it.

Comment: thx for your reply, could you please give more details for the proof?

Comment: Lemma: $E^P Z = \alpha E^{P_1} Z + (1-\alpha) E^{P_2} Z$.  Corollary: $Y = \alpha Y_1 + (1-\alpha) Y_2$.  Also useful: since $P_1 \ll P$, $\operatorname{esssup}_{P_1} Z \le \operatorname{esssup}_{P} Z$.

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply!

Comment: @Nate in general it is not true that $Y=\alpha Y_1+(1-\alpha)Y_2$, see my answer below. Or, to have a quick glance, think of Bayes' formula

Comment: I think you should clarify the definition of $esssup$. Since in real analysis and in probability theory, their definitions are different.

Answer (score 3):

Let me denote (for consistency) by $\mathbb{P}_0$, $\mathbb{P}_1$ the given
probabilities (rather than $\mathbb{P}_1$, $\mathbb{P}_2$), and set
$\mathbb{P}_\alpha=(1-\alpha)\mathbb{P}_0 + \alpha\mathbb{P}_1$. Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be
any probability such that $\mathbb{P}_0\ll\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}_1\ll\mathbb{Q}$
(any $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ would be fine in fact, but it does not matter).
Then $\mathbb{P}_\alpha\ll\mathbb{Q}$ and $G_\alpha=(1-\alpha)G_0 + \alpha G_1$,
where $G_\alpha=\frac{d\mathbb{P}_\alpha}{d\mathbb{Q}}$.

It is easy to check (see below) that
$$
  Y_\alpha
    = \frac{\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG_\alpha|\mathcal{G}]}{\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G_\alpha|\mathcal{G}]}
    = \frac{(1-\alpha)\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG_0|\mathcal{G}]+\alpha\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG_1|\mathcal{G}]}
      {(1-\alpha)\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G_0|\mathcal{G}]+\alpha\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G_1|\mathcal{G}]}.
$$
To prove the claimed inequality, it is sufficient
to notice that the real function
$$
  \alpha
    \mapsto\frac{(1-\alpha)x_0 + \alpha x_1}{(1-\alpha)p_0 + \alpha p_1}
$$
is either non--decreasing or non--increasing.

To conclude, let me prove that, if $\mathbb{P}\ll\mathbb{Q}$ and $G=\frac{d\mathbb{P}}{d\mathbb{Q}}$,
then
$$
  \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]
    = \frac{\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG|\mathcal{G}]}{\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G|\mathcal{G}]}.
$$
First, if $A=\{\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G|\mathcal{G}]=0\}$, then
$$
  \mathbb{P}[A]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G \mathbf{1}_A]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G|\mathcal{G}]\mathbf{1}_A\bigr]
    = 0
$$
and the formula makes sense. For every $A\in\mathcal{G}$,
$$
  \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG|\mathcal{G}]\mathbf{1}_A\bigr]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG\mathbf{1}_A]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X\mathbf{1}_A]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}\bigl[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]\mathbf{1}_A\bigr]
$$
$$
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]G\mathbf{1}_A\bigr]
    = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G|\mathcal{G}]\mathbf{1}_A\bigr],
$$
therefore $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[XG|\mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[G|\mathcal{G}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using $E_1,E_2$ for the two expectations, if for any $A\in\mathcal{G}$ we have $E_i(X 1_A) \le C P_i(A)$ then the same holds for the convex combination.